# how to solder rotary pot

Tags: soldering, potentiometer

[image]

Dear all, I was designing a PCB which contains a pot like the one in the picture. I know how to connect the three pins in the left. However, can anyone tell me what are the rest two pins (the small plate in the front and back) used for and how to connect them? Shall I connect them to ground? Thanks a lot

Comment: The datasheet should tell if it has any connections, as well as a multimeter test, but most of the time they are only for physical stability.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: I guess you mean *mechanical* stability (because electricity, optics and many other things are also *physical*).

Comment: @Curd: are they? try asking that on philosophy.SE ...

Comment: @PlasmaHH: well, I think the word *physical* can have several slightly different meanings. One is more narrow and supports how you used it and another is broader and includes anything being related to physics. I think it should better be discussed on English Language & Usage SE ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hookups on the sides are there to provide mechanical stability: you don't want to stress the contacts every time you rotate the pot. They can be safely connected to GND, or left unconnected (that is, you still provide pads and solder the pot to them, but these pads can have no connection to anything else on the PCB).

Answer (score 1):

They are mechanical supports to avoid stress on the leads while you turn the knob that could cause them to fail.

The case is most likely isolated from the leads (double check that) and does not need to be grounded.